# perforce root directory path

Tags: command-line, perforce

How can I get the perforce root directory path. I've searched online and I've tried solution such as

```
p4 -F %clientRoot% -ztag info
```

However the results returned were empty, but when i run this command:

```
p4 clients -u jmartini
```

I get these results:

> Client jma_HP001 2017/10/19 root C:\projects\john 'Created by
>   jmartini. '

How can I simply just get the root directory path from command line. I would expect my results to be this:

> C:\projects\john

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `p4 info` doesn't return the current client root, your shell does not have `P4CLIENT` set correctly.  To fix this, you can do:

```
p4 set P4CLIENT=jma_HP001
```

From this point on, other commands (including the `p4 -F %clientRoot% -ztag info` you tried to run first) will return results relative to that client workspace.

If you want to just get the client root out of the `clients` command you can do:

```
p4 -F %domainMount% clients -u jmartini
```

or:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %Root% clients -u jmartini
```

Note that if the user owns multiple clients this will get you multiple lines of output.

To figure out the formatting variables you can use with the -F flag, try running commands with the `-e` or -`Ztag` global options:

```
p4 -e clients -u jmartini
p4 -Ztag clients -u jmartini
```

More on the `-F` flag in this blog article: https://www.perforce.com/blog/fun-formatting